# Writing a wrapper for an async method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have a `TransactionOperator` class which exposes the following static async method:

```
public static async Task<bool> ProcessTransactionAsync(Transaction transaction)
{
    var someTransactionOperator = ...; // get appropriate operator
    // some code here
    bool success = await someTransactionOperator.Process(transaction);
    // some more code
    return bool;
}
```

Now, I want to provide a wrapper instance method in the `Transaction` class. My question is, which would be the correct/recommended way of writing it? I'm leaning towards #2 because it *feels right*, but I don't have any supporting arguments for that choice.

```
// Option 1
public bool ProcessAsync()
{
    return TransactionOperator.ProcessTransactionAsync(this).Result;
}

// Option 2
public Task<bool> ProcessAsync()
{
    return TransactionOperator.ProcessTransactionAsync(this);
}

// Option 3 (compiler warning because there's no 'await' operator)
public async Task<bool> ProcessAsync()
{
    return TransactionOperator.ProcessTransactionAsync(this).Result;
}

// Option 4
public async Task<bool> ProcessAsync()
{
    return await TransactionOperator.ProcessTransactionAsync(this);
}
```

Comment: Considering that the first method is non-asynchronous, first you need to decide if you need/want the asynchronous nature of the method to propagate out of the method.

Comment: Both option 2 and 4 work. Option 3 plain doesn't work and Option 1 is dangerous as hell (read will leave you in a deadlock).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The instance method `TransactionOperator.Process(Transaction transaction)`, which the first function I posted calls, waits on a response from the network so I believe it is a good place to add an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Option 2 will let you await outside your method, and i belive Option 4 should be `public async bool ProcessAsync()
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 2 is the best option. Option 4 is logically equivalent but has more overhead.

Options 1 and 3 are flat-out wrong. They both block synchronously (even though option 3 is `async`, it behaves synchronously). [Exposing synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods is not recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). Among other problems, you can [cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (as I explain on my blog).

Comment: Could you explain why option 4 has more overhead?

Comment: @wensveen: It applies an `async` state machine to that method.